# url is empty if device is locked android?

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-intent, android-service

I am working on app, i set a service and getting a url from socket. it is working fine if device is unlocked but if device is locked it work open browser but url is empty for this.can some one tell what is issue??
my code is here.

```
    public class SocketService extends Service {
            Socket socket;
            private ServerSocket serverSocket;
            BufferedReader in = null;
            static String url=null;
            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate();
                new Task().execute();

            }
                private class Task extends AsyncTask <Void, Integer, Void> {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {    
                        try {
                            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6066);

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try {
                            while (true) {
                                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                                try {
                                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                                     try {
                                         StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                                         String line;
                                         while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                                             total.append(line);
                                         }                   
                                         url = total.toString();
                                         Log.d("NETWORK-RECEIVE","Message!:"+url);
                                        // String url2 = "http://www.cashsource.systelligence.com";
                                            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                                            startActivity(i);
                                     } catch (IOException e) {
                                         e.printStackTrace();
                                         Log.d("NETWORK-RECEIVE", "Something goes wrong: IOException");
                                     }
                                } finally {
                                    socket.close();
                                }
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        finally {
                            try {
                                serverSocket.close();                               

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        return null;
                    }
                }

            @Override
            public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            }

            @Override
            public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

        }
```

help me what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the complete code?have you used some BoradcastReceiver for Device Lock/Unlock state?if yes try to look for problem in that code.Because the service code seems fine .

Comment: I have no code for screen lock or unlock screen and have no receiver, this is complete code